# unittest in tensorflow, python session_test.py, got a exception

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run session_test.py from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/session_test.py, So in my anaconda, tensorflow virtual env, I went to the corresponding directory in tensorflow like ../master/tensorflow/python/client/.. and run

`python session_test.py`

I got exception info like this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "session_test.py", line 32, in 
>       from tensorflow.core.protobuf import cluster_pb2
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'cluster_pb2'

What package I should install or related documents that I could read about it. Is there anyone trying to do the same thing, run those unit test coming along with each module in tensorflow repo?
Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line was added just a couple of weeks ago ([see commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/f28935a7d280b6ba75fe93fe35783d87b9cc2ec9)), and relates to a new feature being implemented in TensorFlow. Unless you have compiled and installed a very bleeding-edge version of TensorFlow you won't be able to run it. Instead, try to run the script corresponding to the version of TensorFlow that you have installed (for example, [this is for version 1.1.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.1.0/tensorflow/python/client/session_test.py), the latest stable release at the time of writing).

Comment: great, I checkout to 1.1.0 tag, it works beautifully, I wonder why they put code that not working in the master branch?,  reputation < 15, can't upvote your answer.   This is my first stackoverflow answer, so exciting. Wish you a great day!

Comment: @YangChao Well, the code works as long as you are using a build of TensorFlow from the same version (that is, if you get the code at master, build TensorFlow yourself and run the script, it will probably work). In any case, unless you are developing TensorFlow itself, it is generally better to stick to one of the stable tags. Also, if you feel the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: my reputation is less than 15, It seems like I can't upvote your answer, I am a newbie to stackoverflow @jdehesa,  is it the check symbol under the vote counter?  Making it green, means I accept it, right?

Comment: @YangChao That's right, it's accepted now, thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you, again, Can you tell me whether you are one of contributors for tensorflow, and is there a 5-steps like thing, that I can apply in which I can more involve with tensorflow project? @jdehesa

Comment: @YangChao I'm afraid I am not really a contributor of TensorFlow. I sent once a minor patch for one of the building scripts, but that's all. The development of TensorFlow is mainly controlled by Google, so most of the knowledge about the project internals is there. They are probably more willing to listen to reported issues than let an outsider be in charge of a particular core feature. That said, you are free to explore the code and, send fixes and maybe even submit something for `tf.contrib` (check out the list of [pull requests](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pulls)).